# How many 104th corps cadets joined the scout regiment?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Most of the 104th cadet corps walked out when they were given choice to join the scouts. But how many of them actually joined the scout regiment?. Plus how many of them are still alive.

Answer (score 8):

The following are the top ten of the 104th training regiment, southern division:

- Mikasa Ackerman
- Reiner Braun
- Bertolt Hoover
- Annie Leonhart
- Eren Yeager
- Jean Kirstein
- Marco Bott
- Connie Springer
- Sasha Blouse
- Krista Lenz

Of these top ten, 8 of them went to join the survey corps.

> The only ones that did not were Annie Leonhart, who joined the Military Police, and Marco Bott who died before he chose his division.

The rest of the known members are:

- Armin Arlert - Survey Corps
- Ymir  - Survey Corps
- Thomas Wagner - No division chosen (deceased)
- Hannah Diamant - No division chosen (deceased)
- Franz Kefka - No division chosen (deceased)
- Samuel Linke-Jackson - No division chosen (deceased)
- Nac Tias - No division chosen (deceased)
- Mylius Zeramuski - No division chosen (deceased)
- Mina Carolina - No division chosen (deceased)
- Daz - Unknown division
- Tom - No division chosen (deceased)
- Floch  - Survey Corps
- Gordon - Survey Corps (deceased)
- Sandra - Survey Corps (deceased)

The following three were in the 104th training regiment, but in another division, hence why two of them were able to join Military Police:

- Marlowe Freudenberg - Survey Corps (deceased)
- Hitch Dreyse -  Military Police
- Boris Feulner  Military Police

From these numbers we see that the answer to your question is: **14** members of the 104th training corps joined the Survey Corps.

However, in the anime I count 18 bodies at the "true salute" scene in episode 16:

[image: True salute 18 cadets]